# Error: could not find or load main class AssignmentNine

Tags: java, program-entry-point

When running the following code I get the error "Error: could not find or load main class Assignment9"

I am a newbie programmer and I was wondering if anyone could please point me in the main direction.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignmentNine
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
  double principal;
  double rate;
  int periods;
  int years;
 System.out.println("Enter the initial principal: ");
 principal = keyboard.nextDouble();
 System.out.println("Enter the interest rate: ");
 rate = keyboard.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter the number of compounding periods per year: ");
 periods = keyboard.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter the number of years: ");
 years = keyboard.nextInt();
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

You state that your error message is:
"Error: could not find or load main class ***Assignment9***"
 And yet your class is called ***AssignmentNine***, a completely different name.
You've a basic problem here: `Assignment9 != AssignmentNine`

Solution: use the **same name** for the java class, for the file, and when trying to compile and run the program.

For example, if your code looks like:

```
public class AssignmentNine {
  // .... more code here    
}
```

Then the file name should be: AssignmentNine.java

Next you'll want to declare your variables.

Comment: sorry about that, my file name is indeed named AssignmentNine.java

Comment: @user2925055: please take care to show us only *real* code, and *real* error messages. Please edit your original question and show us what's really going on.

Comment: sorry about that, I think I fixed it.

Comment: @user2925055: fixed "it" as in fixed your question, or fixed your problem?

Comment: I think I fixed my question format, I'm new to stackoverflow so if there is any other tips that will make my etiquette on here better do please let me know. I'm still working on fixing the error I'm getting.

Comment: @user2925055: your error message is the same as previous and so is your class name, and again they are not the same. Again, you must fix that as they must be the same.

Comment: I got it to work by switching from the program "Geany" to using the program "eclipse" to write my code. A friend told me that he uses it and upon using it I have no more problems... This may be a cop out form solving the actual problem.